# Angular Bootstrap table column value setting according to a condition

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I created a data table using angular bootstrap. The data are from an scope variable. But there is a column that needs to be set after some conditions met.

```
$scope.users = [
{name:'David',age:15,city:'NYC'},
{name:'Rick',age:25,city:'Boston'},
{name:'Don',age:20,city:'Boston'},
{name:'Luis',age:10,city:'Florida'},
{name:'Harry',age:30,city:'Boston'},
{name:'Dravid',age:28,city:'Texas'}
];

$('#bootTable').bootstrapTable({
    data : $scope.users,
    sortName: 'name',
    sortOrder: 'asc',
    columns: [
    {
        field: 'name',
        title: 'Name',
        sortable: true
    }, 
    {
        field: 'age', /* condition should be checked before setting value */
        title: 'Category',
        sortable: true          
    }, 
    {
        field: 'city',
        title: 'City'
    }
    ]   
});
```

**So far the category will display as the age itself.**
But the category column should be `"Child" if the age < 21` or if the `age >= 21 it should be "Adult"`

how can I achieve this. Any ideas will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conditional value

```
{{age < 21 ? "Child" : "Adult"}}
```

I don't know why you are writing so much script to sort the table, we can use like this

```
<td ng-click="sortType = 'age'; sortDesc = !sortDesc">
  Age
  <span ng-show="sortType != 'Age'" class="fa fa-sort"></span>
  <span ng-show="sortType == 'Age' && sortDesc" class="fa fa-sort-asc"></span>
  <span ng-show="sortType == 'Age' && !sortDesc" class="fa fa-sort-desc"></span>
</td>
```

or [check this](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1182/angularjs-search-and-sort-on-table-data)

Comment: Thanks for this. but how can i change the code in the question to reflect this idea?

Comment: <div ng-bind-template="{{age < 21 ? "Child" : "Adult"}}"></div> OR
<div>{{age < 21 ? "Child" : "Adult"}}</div>

Comment: this is html. And it may work. But how can I edit the script code I posted to achieve this